# How to transpile React ES6 classes using Grunt + Browserify + Reactify?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to use the new ES6 React classes that was introduced with React v0.13, but I am unable to get it to compile correctly. Say I have the following React component defined in the new class syntax:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  import React from 'react'; 

  class _UserDashboard extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return(
                <div className="user-dashboard">
                    <Books />
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
    export const UserDashboard = React.createClass(_UserDashboard.prototype);

}());
```

The trouble I run into here is that at compile time using Grunt and Browserify and a [Reactify](https://github.com/andreypopp/reactify) transform, Reactify throws an error when it encounters the import keyword:

> ReactifyError: /Users/****/Sites/***/assets/js/components/UserDashboard.jsx: Parse Error: Line 7: Unexpected reserved word while parsing file: /Users/****/Sites/****/assets/js/components/UserDashboard.jsx

The problem here seems to have to do with Reactify's use of react-tools, see [here](https://github.com/andreypopp/reactify/issues/60) and [here](https://github.com/andreypopp/reactify/issues/58). But I'm not sure if it is possible to enable the `es6module` option within Reactify yet.

I tried these two variations to no avail:

```
...
transform: [[ 'reactify', {'es6module': true} ]]
...
```

and

```
...
transform: [[ 'reactify', {'es6':true, 'es6module':true} ]]
...
```

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 18):

You should be able to do all of this with [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) and [babelify](https://github.com/babel/babelify) (the corresponding Browserify plugin).

Babel itself is an ES6+ to ES5 transpiler, but it comes with [first class JSX support](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/jsx/):

> #### JSX and React
>
> Babel works perfectly with React, featuring a built-in JSX transformer.

Your Browserify transform would become:

```
{
  "browserify": {
    "transform": ["babelify"]
  }
}
```

---

**Edit:** As of Babel 6, many components have been moved out into a separate presets packages which you'll need to install and include in the transform command.

For React and JSX, you'll need [`babel-preset-react`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-react).

For ES6, you'll need [`babel-preset-es2015`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-es2015)

Together these can be specified in the transform.

```
transform: [[babelify, { presets: ["react", "es2015"] }]]
```

Comment: That seemed to work, but now the destructuing assignment, e.g. `...other`, is not working.

Comment: That's odd, as Babel definitely [supports it](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es6/#default-rest-spread). Are you getting a compile time error, or just the wrong generated code?

Comment: I fixed it, but I had to add the `stage 0` option. so `"transform: [ ["babelify", {"stage": 0}] ]`.

Comment: Dan, I'm not sure if I should mark your answer as an answer because although it is a solution, it's not a solution for reactify...

Comment: That's down to your discretion, it depends on your perspective of [the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Was the core of problem not being able to get ES6 classes, or was it that Reactify was not working?

Answer (score 4):

Babelify is a best option for my point of view. Small clarification to @Dan's answer. For the babel v 6.0 you will need to install 2 preset.

1. ES2015
2. React

with something similar to `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-react` and `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015` commands and then specify this in babelify settings with: `transform: [[babelify, {presets: ["es2015", "react"]}]]`

And if in your code you use some newest react features like `...other` for example, you also need add `stage-0` preset.